# Using a format string with literal braces

Tags: python

```
Code = "00000"
Number = "111-111-1111"
output="{\r\n      \"Code\":\"{0}\",\r\n    \"PhNumber\": \"{1}\"\r\n}".format(Code, Number)

print(output)
```

Keep getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./prog.py", line 3, in 
KeyError: '\r\n      "Code"'

Comment: Are you trying to generate JSON? Why don't you just use `json.dumps`?

Comment: E.g., `output = json.dumps({'Code': Code, 'PhNumber': Number}', indent=6)`.

Comment: The problem isn't with the printing, it's with the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the entire string in an additional set of curly braces in order to prevent the outermost braces from being interpreted as a formatting-placeholder.

```
output = "{{\r\n      \"Code\":\"{0}\",\r\n    \"PhNumber\": \"{1}\"\r\n}}".format(Code, Number)
```